# Перегружаемые бинарные операторы С# (true и false)

Tags: c#, массивы, перегрузка-операторов

Помогите пожайлуста с заданием: перегрузить операторы в таких случаях : true – проверить ли ровны два массива char. Но проблема в том, что я не могу передать два массива в перегрузку операторов и не могу придумать как обойтись без этого. Заранее благодарна Вам!

Мой код:

```
    class MyString
    {
        private char[] words;
        public char[] Words { get; set; }

        private int length;
//прочие методы 
   public static bool operator true(MyString op1, MyString op2)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<op1.words.Length;i++)
            {
                if (op1.words[i] == op2.words[i])
               {
                  return true;
               }
            }
            return false;
        }
        public static bool operator false(MyString op1, MyString op2)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < op1.words.Length; i++)
            {
             if( op1.words[i] != op2.words[i])
               {
                   return true;
               }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    class MyString : IEnumerable<char>
    {
        public char[] Words { get; set; }

        public static bool operator ==(MyString obj1, MyString obj2) => obj1.SequenceEqual(obj2);

        public static bool operator !=(MyString obj1, MyString obj2) => !obj1.SequenceEqual(obj2);

        public IEnumerator<char> GetEnumerator() => (Words as IEnumerable<char>).GetEnumerator();

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }
```